# Does guava have a method to generate random strings?

Tags: java, random, guava

Apache Commons has a method to generate random string

```
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10)
```

Does guava hava a similar method?

Comment: Not...really.  You can convert a random string of bytes (from a `Random` of your choice) to alphanumeric with `BaseEncoding`, though.

Comment: Why not use the Commons method?

Answer (score 16):

It all depends on your needs, for some cases you can use the following:

```
private final Random random = new Random(); // or SecureRandom

String generate() {
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[5];
    random.nextBytes(buffer);
    return BaseEncoding.base64Url().omitPadding().encode(buffer); // or base32()
}
```

Comment: Interesting... How is result looks like?